# Finding the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{4^{n}}{n\left ( 2n+1 \right )\binom{2n}{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Since
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{4^{n}}{n\left ( 2n+1 \right )\binom{2n}{n}} =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }   \frac{4^{n}  \Gamma \left ( n \right )\Gamma \left ( n+1 \right )}{ \Gamma \left ( 2n+2 \right )} =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }   \frac{4^{n} \operatorname{B}\left ( n+1,n+1 \right )}{n},$$

then 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }   \frac{4^{n} \operatorname{B}\left ( n+1,n+1 \right )}{n} =\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }  \frac{4^{n}}{n} \left ( t(1-t) \right )^{n} dt.$$

Now, I've been stuck here for a day and cannot find this infinite sum.

Please give me some advice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The integral of the sum is the same as the sum of the integral, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the power series for $\ln (1-x)$, this is the easily evaluated$$-\int_0^1\ln (1-4t(1-t))dt=-2\int_0^1 \ln |1-2t|dt=-4\int_0^{1/2}\ln (1-2t)dt.$$

Comment: what happen if we bound  summation from 1 to 1000 ?

Comment: @ABCDEFGuser157844 I doubt there's a nice analytic treatment for very large but finite bounds.